# Loading CSV to Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm new to python but I'm trying to run a regression with a bunch of different variables. So far I've got it down to Scikit. I've been searching for hours but can't seem to find a way to import the data and then run a linear regression on it while returning the coefficients of each variable. Any help is much appreciated. I have 15 columns that I want to run against the X.

```
X = Margin
Ys = A1, B1, C1, D1 etc.
```

Example set below:

```
Margin,A1
-8,110.7
-10,112
-1,106.7
9,109
-9,107.5
1,108.1
-19,109.2
```

Here's what I've got so far I know it's not much

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looped regression model in Python/Sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388624/looped-regression-model-in-python-sklearn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a convention in machine learning we consider X as the features and Y as the target.

If you want to run a linear regression and extract the coefficients, you can do the following :

```
# import the needed libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Import the data
data = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")

# Specify the features and the target
target = 'Margin'
features = data.columns.tolist() # This is the column names of your data as a list
features.remove(target) # We remove the target from the list of features

# Train the model
model = LinearRegression() # Instantiate the model
model.fit(data[features].values, data[target].values) # fit the model to the data
print(features) # Returns the name of each feature
print(model.coef_) # Returns the coefficients for each feature (in the same order of your features)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you.  One question  I have for data.columns do I put data.A1 (column name is A1)? Do I need to list out each column? Like I'd do data.A1, data.A2 or how? Sorry I am new to this and just trying to learn best. Thanks! I am receiving the error though: Traceback (most recent call last): line 11, in <module>
    features.remove(target) # We remove the target from the list of features
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: I edited my answer. We need to transform data.columns to a list to use .remove

Comment: If you want the p-values, R-squared, etc. I suggest you take a look to another library like statsmodels. Here's a great tutorial : https://datatofish.com/statsmodels-linear-regression/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks is there any way to get a summary report similar to what is done when a regression is run in Excel or R? Basically would love the R squared for it and the p-value for each. Not sure if that changes it all up

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Super helpful stuff